# When exactly is enemy team composition info in the Tab-screen updated?

Tags: overwatch

When you start a match in Overwatch you can't see enemies' picks. In the middle of the match - you can press Tab and see them.

What happens when some enemy switches hero in the middle of a match? Can I press Tab and see the change immediately? Or does someone on my team need to detect the new hero first? Or do I personally have to see it on the map? When exactly is my Tab-screen updated?

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, after the time at the beginning of a match where you can't see enemy picks at all, the tab screen shows enemy changes in real time.

Comment: I think it's on a slight delay, but only by 1-3 seconds.